# Why printf doesn't print what I feed it with?

Tags: c, encoding

```
printf("%s\n", "ああ");
```

It outputs :

```
ã‚ã‚
```

What else should I do to print it correctly?

Comment: What platform, locale and encoding do you have?

Comment: What encoding is your source file using? Does your compiler accept that encoding? What encodings does your runtime environment support? What encoding is your terminal expecting?

Comment: @dalle, Does the code need to change when printing multibyte characters?

Comment: @dalle That is irrelevant since the transition from internal encoding to external is done by the C standard library.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: So the encoding of the .c file does not matter? Doesn't the platform matter either, Windows have poor support for UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @dalle What matters is the encoding of the file. Most compilers should have no issues with UTF-8 source code, since that is the generally accepted standard for Unicode text files. System locale should have zero effect on this. Since there is a standard C way to deal with this, the platform doesn't matter either.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Platform *shouldn't* matter but it *does*. VisualC++ has issues with UTF-8 source code. Locale of the application does matter (for Windows at least).

Comment: @dalle Got any references for that (VS not working with UTF-8 sources)? If you set a different locale in your application then the system locale, then yes, it will matter.

Comment: @new_perl: To explain your output: The string "ああ" encoded in UTF-8 is the byte sequence {0xE3 0x81 0x82 0xE3 0x81 0x82}. This byte sequence in the Windows-1252 encoding is the Unicode character sequence {U+00E3 <invalidchar> U+201A U+00E3 <invalidchar> U+201A}, as 0x81 is invalid in Windows-1252 encoding and not output to the console. U+00E3 is 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE' and U+201A is 'SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK'.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that's unicode, compile with a C99 compiler

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
  wchar_t buff[3]; // = L"ああ";
  buff[0] = buff[1] = L'\U00003042';
  buff[2] = 0;
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wprintf(L"%ls\n", buff);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So the only multibyte encoding that c accepts is unicode? Can it be utf8 or other encodings?

Comment: @new_perl If you are talking about the string literals (or the entire code itself), then yes. UTF-8 is the preferred way to store text files. But you can actually use different encodings if your compiler can correctly process the data.

Comment: @pmg You are missing locale setup. This will work only if the internal encoding is matching the system encoding (so on Windows it will work).

Comment: @new_perl: Unicode isn't a multibyte encoding. C doesn't mandate a unicode character set or any specific multibyte encoding, it's dependent on your implementation what encodings you can use. Personally, I prefer to keep my source in US-ASCII and keep all localized resource strings external to the source.

Comment: @Charles Bailey ,`Unicode isn't a multibyte encoding`,what is it then?

Comment: @new_perl: It's a standard for a character coding system. That is, it is a list of standard characters with universal identifying numbers. Those characters can by encoded in many different ways, some of which are multibyte encoding schemes like UTF-8.

Comment: @new_perl Well, Unicode isn't an encoding. You can encode Unicode using different encodings (UCS-2/4, UTF-8/16/32,....).

Comment: @new_perl Unicode isn't an encoding at all, it's just a mapping of code points to characters. UTF-{8,16,32} are encodings (of Unicode text).

Comment: @Charles Bailey ,But my editor allows me to save it in Unicode,what does it mean then?

Comment: @new_perl Well, that the author of the editor doesn't know what Unicode means :-D

Comment: @new_perl: as per the [unicode faq](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), "starting with Unicode 2.0 (July 1996)" Unicode is "a 21-bit code space". Some of the possible encodings are multibyte encodings :-)

Comment: @new_perl Unicode is a mapping of different characters (and character related entities) to unique identifiers. Specific Unicode encodings map these unique identifiers to a binary representation.

Comment: @new_perl No. Unicode has absolutely nothing to do with encoding. Again, Unicode is a mapping of characters (and character related entities) to unique identifiers. It doesn't say anything about the way these identifiers should be represented in computer memory.

Comment: @new_perl Well that's what it is. Unicode is an abstraction. We needed a universal way to describe all possible characters. So we got Unicode. But when you have characters mapped to some identifiers, then you also need a way to store them in memory (that is what an encoding describes). You can just take the identifiers and represent them 1:1 as they are (basically what UTF-32 does), or you can do various thing like use only one byte for most common characters (UTF-8).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Actually the Unicode Standard describes several different different encodings for the Unicode Character Set. Stating that Unicode has absolutely nothing to do with encoding is wrong. The Unicode Standard describes the mapping from a Character to a Codepoint, and describes several mappings from Codepoints to Code Unit Sequences (called Encoding Form), and from Code Unit Sequences to Byte Sequences (called Encoding Scheme).

Comment: @dalle Oh, you are right. I didn't know that Unicode encodings are actually part of the standard.

Answer (score 4):

The absolutely correct version should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
        wchar_t *s1 = L"♠♣♥♦";
        wchar_t *s2 = L"Příšerně žluťoučký kůň";
        wchar_t *s3 = L"ああ";

        setlocale(LC_ALL,""); /* pull system locale for correct output */
        wprintf(L"%ls\n%ls\n%ls\n",s1,s2,s3); /* print all three strings */
        return 0;
}
```

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments by R.., you can actually use `printf` instead of `wprintf`. The only limitation is that the formating string must be `const char*` for the `printf` instead of `const wchar_t*` for `wprintf`. So no wide characters in the formatting string.

Comment: I got this: `error: converting to execution character set: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
`

Comment: @new_perl Make sure that you are storing the file with a correct encoding. UTF-8 should do for most compilers.

Comment: This is not "absolutely" correct in that it's not universally portable. This web page uses UTF-8. If you take the bytes from this code, your compiler must be using UTF-8 to interpret the source and the target system must also be using UTF-8. There are plenty of C environments that either don't use or don't support UTF-8 but use some other encoding.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Seriously, what compiler doesn't support UTF-8 source code? Don't mix runtime environment with the encoding of the source code.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: There are many, especially embedded compilers, native compilers on some IBM systems that I've used. There are many more that don't use UTF-8 by default.

Comment: @CharlesBailey And they still support C99?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, Support for C99 doesn't automatically mean it it knows how to handle UTF-8 encoding. However it still has to support *some* kind of encoding that handles non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Some of them support some of much of C99, not many compilers have 100% conformance to C99. Technically there's no reason you couldn't have a confroming C99 implementation whose source and execution character set were a subset of ASCII.

Comment: @AlexB: Really? What non-ASCII characters does C99 require support for?

Comment: @CharlesBailey I suppose if you get technical, it doesn't *really* have to support any non-ASCII characters, but then why would a compiler implement wide literals if they could not be used?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Why non-ASCII? ASCII isn't a mandated encoding. And I actually find it much more believable that a system doesn't support ASCII, than that a system supports wide characters, but doesn't work with UTF-8 encoded files.

Comment: @AlexB: I've worked on some systems which have only a custom display with just an archaic non-ISO 8-bit character set. The "wide" character functions are required for C99 conformance but you'd never need to use them. As far as I was aware (but I may be mistaken), on such a system it would be legal to have `wchar_t` use the same representation as `char` and the wide character functions identical to the narrow ones.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: When I said "subset of ASCII", what I really meant but didn't actually say was "a character set that includes the required basic characters of C". Of course these characters are a subset of what US-ASCII supports but you don't have to use a US-ASCII based character system to represent them. I'm sorry for the confusion my inexact use of terminology caused.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use `wprintf` here, and in fact it will badly break your program if any non-wide stdio functions are used with `stdout` elsewhere!! Just use `printf` with the `%ls` format specifier. For the most part, the wide stdio functions should be Considered Harmful and never used.

Comment: @R.. Hmm, didn't realize that you can use `%ls` with `printf`. Good to know :)

Comment: @R.. ,how can `printf` work with such characters as `L'\U00003042'`(provided in @pmg's example), say, it contains NULL character,but not in the end of string, it has no way to detect whether it gets to the end unless it detects the encoding internally...

Comment: @JeRog Easily. `printf` knows both the internal and external encoding. The internal encoding is given by the platform (UTF-16 on Windows, UCS-2 on Windows 2000 and older, UTF-32 on most UNIX systems), external encoding is given by the current locale.

Comment: `L'\U00003042'` does not "contain null character". It's an integer (of type `wchar_t`) whose value is 0x3042 on any sane system, but whatever its value is, it's a single integer, not a string of bytes.

Comment: @R.. ,the point is `printf` won't know that unless it knows the corresponding encoding, does `printf` know that in the first place?

Comment: How does printf deal with %ls internally?Is there any implementation code available?

Comment: @new_perl: As if the conversion were performed by `wcsrtombs`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have to use `wprintf`, the wide character version of `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, C89 doesn't support mutli-byte encoding for string **literals** (only ASCII), standard C functions can handle input/output with other encodings, provided it can be treated as an opaque blob.

E.g., this one will be correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", "\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\x82");
}
```

This one *may* be wrong (if you expect it to print the number of characters):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    printf("%lu\n", strlen("\xe3\x81\x82\xe3\x81\x82"));
}
```

The compiler *may* interpret source input as UTF-8, but it's not guaranteed. For example, GCC does seem to read UTF-8 source files correctly:

```
hexdump -Cv b.c
00000000  23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65  20 3c 73 74 64 69 6f 2e  |#include <stdio.|
00000010  68 3e 0a 69 6e 74 0a 6d  61 69 6e 28 29 0a 7b 0a  |h>.int.main().{.|
00000020  20 20 20 20 70 72 69 6e  74 66 28 22 25 73 5c 6e  |    printf("%s\n|
00000030  22 2c 20 22 e3 81 82 e3  81 82 22 29 3b 0a 7d 0a  |", "......");.}.|
00000040
```

Note the same string is the literal (`e3 81 82 e3 81 82`) and is exactly the same byte sequence that gets printed out:

```
./a.out | hexdump -Cv
00000000  e3 81 82 e3 81 82 0a                              |.......|
00000007
```

If your locale isn't UTF-8, or your editor saved the file with encoding other than UTF-8, I suspect the result will be different.